# How do i only allow specific email to login into my page

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

There are two sides, Admin and Users. I am using the same database in firebase for both Users and Admin. It means that Users that are registered in my firebase authentication, can login to Admin webpage. How do i allow only specific admin's email to login into the Admin page.

For example:
Admin has an email of admin@admin.com

User has various email like 123@gmail.com, 222@gmail.com and etc.

What i want is only to allow admin@admin.com to be able to login into the Admin page but restrict login for User emails to login to the Admin page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a Javascript, a simple solution would be to [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the `email` String on the `@`, which will return you an Array of substrings and compare the second part which is the domain. Then, you could condition the rest of your code to work only if the criteria is `true`.

An example would be:

```
const allowedEmailDomain = 'admin.com';

const email = 'test@admin.com';

if (email.split('@')[1] === allowedEmailDomain) {
  // do something, we accept this email
} else {
  // return an error or do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I make the assumption that, on the back-end side, your application is correctly secured, i.e. you have security rules in your database that only allow the users with an "admin" profile/role to read or write "admin" data in the database.

If this is not the case you MUST set correct security rules, since **securing your Firebase instance only from a front-end perspective is not sufficient**, as it is not very difficult to reverse engineer your app code and write some JavaScript code that will interact with your back-end. For that you could use [Custom Claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims).

So, with this assumption, it means that you need to adapt your front end in such a way the admin screens are only seen by the admin users.

One of the best answer is again to use Custom Claims, as explained here https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#access_custom_claims_on_the_client (Section "Access custom claims on the client") and in this official Firebase video: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#access_custom_claims_on_the_client

---

Note that trying to block a user based on his email domain may not be a good solution as it is easy, in few lines of JavaScript code, to register to your Firebase project as a user with a mail like whatever@admin.com or with any other email (using [createUserWithEmailAndPassword](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword))

Answer (score 0):

Just block every other domain as @admin.com.

```
$allowed_domains = array("admin.com");
$email_domain = array_pop(explode("@", $email));
if(!in_array($email_domain, $allowed_domains)) {
    // Not an authorised email 
}
```

It's simply. Make an array for allowed domains, explode by @, get the last element of the array and check if it exists in the allowed domains array.